# Jquery with Ajax post not working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-post

I am trying to make a simple game and I'm not very good with jQuery. The code I have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#deposit').click(function(){       
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                Money : $('#input_money').val()
            },
            success: function(data){ 
                $('#display').html(data.value);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And the display is this:

```
<input id="input_money" name="input_money" type="text" size="40"><br><br>
<button id="deposit">Deposit Money</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

For the back end, I am using this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Money'])){
    $value = $_POST['Money'];   
} else {
    $value = "";
}
echo json_encode(array("value"=>$value));
```

Can anyone help me out? I plan to add the `$value` into a database after it shows up on the main page.

Thanks

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you're facing? What error do you get?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe the actual problem you are facing so we can try to lead you on the right path

Comment: Are you running this on locally ?

Comment: are you printing a content header first?

Comment: Check your console for errors also.

Answer (score 1):

I fired this on my serv, find it at: [this link](http://webforless.dk/jq.php)

It works just fine.
Heres the source, just like yours.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#deposit').click(function(){      
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                Money : $('#input_money').val()
            },
            success: function(data){ 
                $('#display').html(data.value);
            }
        });
   });
});
  </script>


<input id="input_money" name="input_money" type="text" size="40"><br><br>
<button id="deposit" type="button">Deposit Money</button>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Hope youll get it to work.
Best regards
Jonas

Comment: Not true. He's json encoding value. So data.value would give you the value back. And $.post is just a shortcut for $.ajax with 'POST' passed in for the `type` attribute.

Comment: Ay. Dident see the Json part in the upload.php file. My bad, that part is now edited.

Comment: changing it from ajax to post won't do anything different as it's more of a cosmetic change to the call. They both do the same thing.

Comment: True. As i said, i would rather use this command than the other, no comment on how it would fix his problem or not.

Comment: True again. Sorry, im still new to this whole stackoverflow thing. Yet, i editet my post to contain code wich works. I hope this is better.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. It wouldn't show up whatever you typed so I had no idea what was wrong. it's working now thanks to jonas's post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested and without Json, but should work straight).

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
<p><input id="input_money" name="input_money" type="text" size="40"></p>
<button id="deposit" type="submit" name="deposit">Deposit Money</button>
</form>

<div id="display"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
       $('#myform').submit(function()
       {   
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();   
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response){ 

                $('#display').html(response);
            },
            error: function(){
            alert('There was an error in AJAX call!');
            }
        });
        return false;
       });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
echo isset($_POST['input_money']) ? htmlentities($_POST['input_money']) : 'no value';
```